# VB 2008 WebBrowser Control: HTML from string leads to javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, webbrowser-control, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to integrate a HTML WYSIWG editor (for example the ckeditor) within a VB 2008 desktop application (an email client).
To provide this I'm using the windows forms web browser control. I'm able to integrate the editor when loading the HTML via `WebBrowser.Url = New Uri(myURI)` no matter if loading from a webserver or from a local HTML file. But when I try to use an HTML string by using `WebBrowser.DocumentText = html` I get an unknown script error (IE script error message) and the editor is not useable. The HTML stays the same.

This don't work (script error):

```
Dim content As String = "<strong>Your mail body</strong>"
Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd""><html>" & _
"<head>" & _
"<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>" & _
"<script src='http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.10/standard/ckeditor.js'></script>" & _
"</head>" & _
"<body>" & _
"<textarea name='editor1' id='editor1'>" & _
content & _
"</textarea>" & _
"<script>" & _
"(function(){ " & _
"CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');" & _
"})();" & _
"</script>" & _
"</body>" & _
"</html>"
WebBrowser.DocumentText = html
```

Storing to temp file works:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Me.tempFile, html, False)
WebBrowser.Url = New Uri(Me.tempFile)
```

Is it possible to use a string based solution or do I have to store it to a temp file first. I prefeer the pure string based solution for data security purposes.

Comment: I get errors even when i store it to a temp file.

Comment: Using a temp file works for me. What error do you get? I'm adding a CDN URL to the example to provide the ckeditor.

Comment: Ok yes now it works (Storing It In a temp).

Comment: Its much easier with temp files! If you prefer the pure string based solution for data security purposes, you could load the html file to the broswer and then delete it.